# Errno 13 Permission Denied when using Tkinter's asksaveasfile

Tags: python, tkinter, save

I am making a tkinter gui for school worksheet generation. The program works perfectly on my own PC, but when tested on another's as a .exe file, it sometimes throws the following error (only sometimes??):

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in _call_
  File "MathGen.py", line 350, in create_doc
  File "tkinter\filedialog.py", line 436, in asksaveasfile
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/steph/Documents/test.docx'
```

The code relating to the save function:

```
for i in range(questnum):
    document.add_paragraph(f'{i + 1}. {questions[i]}\n\n')
f = asksaveasfile(initialfile='Untitled.pdf', defaultextension="*.*", filetype=[('Word Document', '*.docx')])
document.save(f.name)
self.final_screen()
```

Comment: The error means exactly what it says: you don’t have permission to write that file or folder.

Comment: What would be programmatic fix for that? There is no dialog popup or anything to change the permissions, and I am trying to give it to colleagues sharing the same network with work computers.

Comment: I can't figure out which logic it is following, as sometimes it works on some computers in some directories, others not at all or spontaneously. So strange, and I just dont understand what is happening.

Comment: You can’t fix it, it’s the OS saying you can’t create the file. The fix should be to pick a different directory or change the permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, any advice to avoid this, or how to force a prompt to accept permissions?

Comment: Bryan's comment included the possible solutions. You either change the permissions of the current directory where this problem is occurring,  or change the directory to one that satisfies the permission requirements.

Comment: A possible "fix" could be if you try to open the exe on the other machine as administrator, that way you'll have all the permissions. enjoy

Comment: you have strange dialog - `initialfile` uses filename with extension `.pdf` but `filetype` filters `'*.docx'` - so you have two different types of files :) Which one do you try to create?

Comment: sometimes system may not allow to write some file when this file is already opened in other program.

Comment: @furas, haha yeah i noticed that error as well. I did a lazy copy + paste from another program. Thanks for the advice, ill try some of these solutions.